# How to export a JTable to a .csv file?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, apache-camel, export-to-csv

Like the title implies, i am looking for a way to export a jtable with data to a `.csv file`. I am not looking for other options then `CSV`, because `CSV` is the requirement for my program.

I have been looking at certain things, like `bindy` of `apache.camel` put I couldn't find enough information to understand how to use it.

What is recommended? If someone has a decent example of the usage of `bindy` I wouldn't mind either.

Friendly regards,

Skillcoil

Answer (score 2):

It is something like that:

```
    public void writeCSVfile(JTable table) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Writer writer = null;
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        int nRow = dtm.getRowCount();
        int nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"), "utf-8"));

            //write the header information
            StringBuffer bufferHeader = new StringBuffer();
            for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
                bufferHeader.append(dtm.getColumnName(j));
                if (j!=nCol) bufferHeader.append(", ");
            }
            writer.write(bufferHeader.toString() + "\r\n");

           //write row information
            for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){
                 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++){
                    buffer.append(dtm.getValueAt(i,j));
                    if (j!=nCol) buffer.append(", ");
                }
                writer.write(buffer.toString() + "\r\n");
            }
        } finally {
              writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/) to generate an Excel file from the JTable then use this code 
from here [Converting XLS to CSV files Using Java](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/converting-xls-to-csv-files-using-java/) to export XLS file to CSV file.

I actually use this way to generate CSV files

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Unfortunatly the table I want to export requires the choice to export to a CSV, XLS or TXT file. So i'll need to find export ways for all 3 (xls I allready got setup). If the method of converting the xls get's accepted, I'll use this.

Answer (score 0):

what about a little for-loop? The TableModel provides all nessesary data, such as row count, column count, and the data.

Comment: I'm being pointed on using Api's or utils more. For example bindy uses annotations to point the route ect, but can't seem to figure it out yet how it works, so I'm trying to find alternatives or even a better solution then I am researching at the moment.

Comment: actually i have no idea about apis, but i have an idea of java. this for-loop i am talking about would be over 10 lines of code... Dont know, if you really have to use a whole api for such a little task?